# Maven build and release multiple interdependant projects

Tags: java, maven, release

I have some existing Maven projects.

They are:

1. aaa (plugin)
2. bbb (jar)
3. ccc (jar)
4. ddd (war)
5. eee (war)

**Project `ddd` is for a customer and `eee` is for another**

They are located in flat structure under `workspace/` folder on disk, and the very same structure is inside svn repo.

This is the project's dependency hierarchy:

```
ddd (war)        
    aaa (plugin)
    bbb (jar)
    ccc (jar)
        bbb (jar)

eee (war)
    ccc (jar)
        bbb (jar)
```

When only `war`s are `SNAPSHOT`s there's no problem in building and releasing

otherwise, i.e.

```
ddd       1.1-SNAPSHOT (war)        
  aaa     2.0          (plugin)
  bbb     2.1-SNAPSHOT (jar)
  ccc     1.3-SNAPSHOT (jar)
    bbb   2.1-SNAPSHOT (jar)
```

I have to do, for building:

1. `bbb> mvn install`
2. `ccc> mvn install`
3. `ddd> mvn compile`

and for release:

1. `bbb> mvn release:prepare release:perform`
2. `ccc> mvn versions:use-releases`
3. `ccc> svn ci -m "updated SNAPSHOT dependencies"`
4. `ccc> mvn release:prepare release:perform`
5. `ddd> mvn versions:use-releases`
6. `ddd> svn ci -m "updated SNAPSHOT dependencies"`
7. `ddd> mvn release:prepare release:perform`

I tried with an aggregator, but

- on building, it compiles non SNAPSHOT dependencies (aaa 2.0 -> compiles aaa 2.1-SNAPSHOT)
- on releasing, it complains about scm, but I don't want the aggregator to be in svn

This is what I need:

- single command build

  - orders SNAPSHOT dependecies
  - installs (or deploy) each SNAPSHOT dependency
  - builds (compile or package or install...) root artifact
- single command release

  - orders SNAPSHOT dependencies
  - releases each SNAPSHOT dependency
  - releases root artifact

This is what I **don't** want:

- a batch build/release script
- put aggregators in svn
- version sharing among projects
- parent becomes an aggregator too

**Is this possible?**

**Alternative best practices? (maybe Jenkins will help?)**

## Should I switch to Gradle??

---

**update**

i see that most of you confuse **parent** with **aggregator**, so i removed it from this question. however,

> [...] You will often see projects that are both parents and aggregators. [...] However, although both POM projects, an aggregator project and a parent project are not one in the same and should not be confused. A POM project may be inherited from - but does not necessarily have - any modules that it aggregates. Conversely, a POM project may aggregate projects that do not inherit from it.

from [A final note on Inheritance v. Aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance_v)

Comment: What do you understand under `aggregator`? You should think about really workign with a multi-module build and change the structure in SVN according to your real structure. What do you mean by version sharing?

Comment: @khmarbaise multi-module should be used when modules will *always* be released together, not as a short-cut to build with a single command.  In my experience *always* is rarely the case

Comment: @NickHolt I didn't said to use it as a short-cut. It looks more and more like a multi module build and the op is trying to going around it.

Comment: @khmarbaise sorry, should have clarified - I generally see multi-module used as a short cut.  In the OPs case, if multi-module were used, a bug fix in ddd (war) would require the aaa through ccc also be released, which, theoretically speaking at least, means they should be regression tested to confirm that no changes have been accidentally introduced

Comment: @NickHolt "multi-module should be used when modules will always be released together" i totally agree.

Comment: @khmarbaise there are **two** multi module builds (ddd and eee) with **common** modules. I'm not trying to go around it, the exact contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just got it in a hacky way... but I'm **not** satisfied.

**If someone will provide a better way to perform a custom recursive release process on maven I'll be glad to change my acceptance!**

parent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-release-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>test-release-parent</name>
    <description>This is the parent pom to test release procedure</description>
    <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <svn.repository>http://svn.mycompany.com/repo1</svn.repository>
        <web.projects>http://www2.mycompany.com/projects</web.projects>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:${svn.repository}/${project.artifactId}</developerConnection>
        <url>${svn.repository}/${project.artifactId}</url>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>ftp.mycompany.com</id>
            <name>mycompany Maven Repository</name>
            <url>ftp://ftp.mycompany.com/maven-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>www2.mycompany.com</id>
            <name>mycompany Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://www2.mycompany.com/maven-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>www2.mycompany.com</id>
            <name>mycompany Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://www2.mycompany.com/maven-repo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>javax:javaee-api:*:*</exclude>
                            <exclude>org.eclipse.persistence:*:*:*</exclude>
                            <exclude>org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:*:*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <rulesUri>http://www.mycompany.com/ruleset.xml</rulesUri>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>
                        String releaseVersion = project.version.substring(0, project.version.indexOf("-"));

                        String nextVersion;
                        int index = releaseVersion.lastIndexOf(".");
                        if(index == -1) nextVersion = (releaseVersion.toInteger() + 1) + "-SNAPSHOT";
                        else
                        {
                            String prefix = releaseVersion.substring(0, index);
                            String suffix = releaseVersion.substring(index + 1);

                            nextVersion = prefix + "." + (suffix.toInteger() + 1) + "-SNAPSHOT";
                        }

                        ant.exec(failonerror: "true", dir: "${basedir}", executable: "cmd")
                        {
                            arg(value: "/c")
                            arg(value: "mvn")
                            arg(value: "validate")
                            arg(value: "-Prelease-align")
                            arg(value: "-Dversion.release=" + releaseVersion)
                            arg(value: "-Dversion.next=" + nextVersion)
                        }

                        ant.exec(failonerror: "true", dir: "${basedir}", executable: "cmd")
                        {
                            arg(value: "/c")
                            arg(value: "mvn")
                            arg(value: "initialize")
                            arg(value: "-Prelease-prepare")
                            arg(value: "-Dversion.release=" + releaseVersion)
                            arg(value: "-Dversion.next=" + nextVersion)
                        }

                        ant.exec(failonerror: "true", dir: "${basedir}", executable: "cmd")
                        {
                            arg(value: "/c")
                            arg(value: "mvn")
                            arg(value: "deploy")
                            arg(value: "-Prelease-perform")
                            arg(value: "-Dversion.release=" + releaseVersion)
                            arg(value: "-Dversion.next=" + nextVersion)
                        }
                    </source>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>buildall</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>execute</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <source>
                                        for(d in project.dependencies)
                                        {
                                            if(d.groupId == "com.mycompany" &amp;&amp; d.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT"))
                                            {
                                                println "installing " + d
                                                ant.exec(failonerror: "true", dir: "${basedir}/../" + d.artifactId, executable: "cmd")
                                                {
                                                    arg(value: "/c")
                                                    arg(value: "mvn")
                                                    arg(value: "install")
                                                    arg(value: "-Pbuildall")
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </source>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>release-align</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>initial-updates</id>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>update-parent</goal>
                                    <goal>use-releases</goal>
                                    <goal>commit</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>release-prepare</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>release-snapshots</id>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>execute</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <source>
                                        if(project.parent != null &amp;&amp; project.parent.groupId == "com.mycompany" &amp;&amp; project.parent.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT"))
                                        {
                                            println "releasing " + project.parent

                                            String releaseVersion = project.parent.version.substring(0, project.parent.version.indexOf("-"));

                                            String nextVersion;
                                            int index = releaseVersion.lastIndexOf(".");
                                            if(index == -1) nextVersion = (releaseVersion.toInteger() + 1) + "-SNAPSHOT";
                                            else
                                            {
                                                String prefix = releaseVersion.substring(0, index);
                                                String suffix = releaseVersion.substring(index + 1);

                                                nextVersion = prefix + "." + (suffix.toInteger() + 1) + "-SNAPSHOT";
                                            }

                                            ant.exec(failonerror: "true", dir: "${basedir}/../" + project.parent.artifactId, executable: "cmd")
                                            {
                                                arg(value: "/c")
                                                arg(value: "mvn")
                                                arg(value: "validate")
                                                arg(value: "-Prelease-align")
                                                arg(value: "-Dversion.release=" + releaseVersion)
                                                arg(value: "-Dversion.next=" + nextVersion)
                                            }

                                            ant.exec(failonerror: "true", dir: "${basedir}/../" + project.parent.artifactId, executable: "cmd")
                                            {
                                                arg(value: "/c")
                                                arg(value: "mvn")
                                                arg(value: "initialize")
                                                arg(value: "-Prelease-prepare")
                                                arg(value: "-Dversion.release=" + releaseVersion)
                                                arg(value: "-Dversion.next=" + nextVersion)
                                            }

                                            ant.exec(failonerror: "true", dir: "${basedir}/../" + project.parent.artifactId, executable: "cmd")
                                            {
                                                arg(value: "/c")
                                                arg(value: "mvn")
                                                arg(value: "deploy")
                                                arg(value: "-Prelease-perform")
                                                arg(value: "-Dversion.release=" + releaseVersion)
                                                arg(value: "-Dversion.next=" + nextVersion)
                                            }
                                        }

                                        for(d in project.dependencies)
                                        {
                                            if(d.groupId == "com.mycompany" &amp;&amp; d.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT"))
                                            {
                                                println "releasing " + d

                                                String releaseVersion = d.version.substring(0, d.version.indexOf("-"));

                                                String nextVersion;
                                                int index = releaseVersion.lastIndexOf(".");
                                                if(index == -1) nextVersion = (releaseVersion.toInteger() + 1) + "-SNAPSHOT";
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    String prefix = releaseVersion.substring(0, index);
                                                    String suffix = releaseVersion.substring(index + 1);

                                                    nextVersion = prefix + "." + (suffix.toInteger() + 1) + "-SNAPSHOT";
                                                }

                                                ant.exec(failonerror: "true", dir: "${basedir}/../" + d.artifactId, executable: "cmd")
                                                {
                                                    arg(value: "/c")
                                                    arg(value: "mvn")
                                                    arg(value: "validate")
                                                    arg(value: "-Prelease-align")
                                                    arg(value: "-Dversion.release=" + releaseVersion)
                                                    arg(value: "-Dversion.next=" + nextVersion)
                                                }

                                                ant.exec(failonerror: "true", dir: "${basedir}/../" + d.artifactId, executable: "cmd")
                                                {
                                                    arg(value: "/c")
                                                    arg(value: "mvn")
                                                    arg(value: "initialize")
                                                    arg(value: "-Prelease-prepare")
                                                    arg(value: "-Dversion.release=" + releaseVersion)
                                                    arg(value: "-Dversion.next=" + nextVersion)
                                                }

                                                ant.exec(failonerror: "true", dir: "${basedir}/../" + d.artifactId, executable: "cmd")
                                                {
                                                    arg(value: "/c")
                                                    arg(value: "mvn")
                                                    arg(value: "deploy")
                                                    arg(value: "-Prelease-perform")
                                                    arg(value: "-Dversion.release=" + releaseVersion)
                                                    arg(value: "-Dversion.next=" + nextVersion)
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </source>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>final-updates</id>
                                <phase>initialize</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>update-parent</goal>
                                    <goal>use-releases</goal>
                                    <goal>set</goal>
                                    <goal>commit</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <newVersion>${version.release}</newVersion>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>release-perform</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>set-next-snapshot</id>
                                <phase>deploy</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>set</goal>
                                    <goal>commit</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <newVersion>${version.next}</newVersion>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>checkin-release</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>checkin</goal>
                                    <goal>tag</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>checkin-snapshot</id>
                                <phase>deploy</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>checkin</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                            <message>auto-generated by release process</message>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

and this is a project pom that uses another project (flatten structure in workspace) as dependency

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-release-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>test-release-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>maven project to test a release process</description>
    <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
    <url>${web.projects}/${project.artifactId}</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>www2.mycompany.com</id>
            <name>mycompany Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://www2.mycompany.com/maven-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:${svn.repository}/${project.artifactId}/trunk</developerConnection>
        <url>${svn.repository}/${project.artifactId}/trunk</url>
    </scm>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-release-dependency</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

just run

```
mvn <some-phase> -Pbuildall
```

to execute `<some-phase>` on current project and `install` on all owned and referenced snapshots (parent and dependencies)

and

```
mvn groovy:execute
```

to perform a release an all owned and referenced snapshots

the idea behind:

- procedure release:

  1. update parent version if exists
  2. update snapshot dependencies if exists
  3. if parent is owned and snapshot

     - release(parent)
  4. for each owned and snapshot dependency

     - release(dependency)
  5. update parent version (MUST exist now)
  6. update owned and snapshot dependencies (MUST exist now)
  7. set project release version (ie from 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.0)
  8. commit changes to scm
  9. tag freeze on scm
  10. perform all maven lifecycle phases till deploy
  11. set project next version (ie from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
  12. commit changes to scm again

Comment: I have done something similar but externalized it as a separate script (incidentally it is also groovy). I actually had tried something similar to what you did but found it was incredibly slow and buggy. Slow because you can't intelligently build in parallel or use your continuous integration servers ability to build in parallel. The versions plugin is also very slow. Buggy because the versions/release plugin sometimes would have issues updating the versions correctly (you have to fork all the time because the pom is changing).

Comment: @AdamGent In the end I coded my own release tool in Java, which uses command line maven invocation only for *effective-pom*s and *clean deploy* with no release/extraneous plugin. All the work made by *versions-maven-plugin* and *maven-release-plugin* is actually performed by Java code. However, when I'll have some spare time, I'll check gradle and eventually migrate all of my projects. I'm very happy with maven dependency management, nevertheless the build/release lifecycle is seriously disappointing.

Comment: Yes the release plugin is... awful. We plan on killing it as well. Despite all the problems with Maven I still prefer it to Gradle. As stupid as this sounds if it weren't for the fact Maven is so declarative (ie XML) I wouldn't have been able to write an external tool to do all the dependency / release stuff. One thing I do that I'm not sure if you do is I check to see if changes actually have been made to upstream dependencies before releasing them (this was actually fairly trick to get right).

Comment: @AdamGent I'm a fan of declarative programming, just don't like the maven build lifecycle implementation that's plugin-centric instead of phase-centric. I don't check for modifications, I recursively collect a list of shapshot artifacts (parent, plugins and dependencies) by scm checkout, so I'm sure I get the latest updates and that no other commit may interfere.

Comment: So you must be releasing dependencies even if there are no changes or am I missing something? For example if you have A depends on B (snapshot version ie latest) if there are no changes in B when you do a release of A you need to tell A to not use the snapshot of B and to not to release B. Otherwise you are needlessly rolling up versions of all dependencies. For example if you have other projects say for example C that depends on B you have to then go update it to point to the latest just because A was released.

Comment: @AdamGent I use the opposite approach. Suppose I have `A@2.0-SNAPSHOT` which depends on `B@5.0-SNAPSHOT` *before* the release. The *release* pom would be `A@2.0 => B@5.0`. Finally, the *after* release pom would be `A@2.1-SNAPSHOT => B@5.0`. So I'll need to **manually** update the dep version reference when I want to use (and subsequently release) an updated version of the dependant artifact (in my case higher level = more frequent update). Furthermore, my release tool checks if the same artifact is used with different versions and eventually aborts the release process.

Comment: I thought you might be doing it that way and it is the canonical way. We used to do it that way and we still do for some cases (you can lock the dependencies on a specific version). What has happened over time is our upstream dependencies change enough that it became irritating to be constantly manually updating the pom to point to the latest snapshot. The versions plugin is supposed to help this but it ends up breaking fairly often partly because you have to have the `SNAPSHOT` dependencies installed/deployed before you can change the dependee pom back to `SNAPSHOT`. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: To be more precise the build *before* would be `A@2.0-SNAPSHOT=>B@5.0-SNAPSHOT`. At release it would be `A@2.0=>B@4.9` (assuming 4.9 was previous release... lets ignore semver for example purposes). Post release it would be `A@2.1-SNAPSHOT=>B@5.0-SNAPSHOT`. That is the build machine put everything back to `SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: Nope, at release, it would be exactly `A@2.0=>B@5.0`. Since the release procedure is recursive (and it is executed in **post-order**!), it will first release `B@5.0` and then, when entering `release(A)`, it will upgrade `A@2.0-SNAPSHOT=>B@5.0-SNAPSHOT` to `A@2.0=>B@5.0` because B has been just released on previous iteration. The inductive step states that an artifact may be released IFF it has no snapshot deps or each snapshot dep has a corresponding release version :)

Comment: Yes I meant for our build process we would not get 5.0 for B because we would detect no changes on B regardless of recursive ordering. The key being we *ignore the changes made by the build machine to B's pom file cause by a previous release* i.e. the changes made to turn it back to a snapshot. That is B hasn't really changed from B 4.9 to 5.0 snapshot. This is the tricky part because we examine the SCM history. I understand how and why your process is different though.

Comment: The consequence of detecting changes **makes our release process idempotent!**. If you rerun the release on the same project and no SCM changes have been made (to dependencies as well) nothing will happen because we detect changes. For yours I believe you will at the minimum release the top level project assuming you have of course gone through and made sure all dependencies are not `SNAPSHOT`. For us that was tedious and caused version drift.

Comment: I see the benefit, but your approach is limited to track only the source code in Configuration Management. Sometimes, although very rarely, the way that artifact is compiled and packaged, using the very same source code, matters for CM purposes and can originate different release versions. In my specific case, some artifact, tipically top level, can be packaged for a specific customer/environment using build flags/profiles. Nevertheless your approach further simplify the release management where it is allowed, so I think I can use it with profit ;) Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to Gradle, but it is probably easier to continue to use Maven with a few minor modifications:

- Add `<modules>` in your `parent` pom in which you specify all your child modules.
- Set the parent version in your child poms to be the same as your parent version, e.g.        `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`.
- Add the project that gets included by the other builds, i.e. `bbb` and `ccc` to the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your parent pom, set their version to be `${project.version}`, and remove their specific versions in `ddd` and `eee`.
- Likewise, add the `aaa` plugin to the `<pluginsManagement>` section of your parent pom, set its version to be `${project.version}` and remove the specific version from the other projects.

Now you can build and release all your builds in one go, e.g. by using the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/).

Comment: I'm sorry, but you pointed exactly what I wrote I **don't want** in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The guys from barchart created a Jenkins plugin: "Maven Cascade Release Plugin"

https://github.com/barchart/barchart-jenkins-cascade-plugin/wiki/User-Manual

This requires that you create a separate 'Layout' project that manages the order in which other projects are to be released:

```
Root layout:
<project>
  <modules>
    <module>a</module>
    <module>ant</module>
    <module>fish</module>
    <module>fish/salmon</module>
    <module>fish/shark</module>
</modules>
```

This project still needs to be in Subversion, it seems, but you can put it in a separate repository, and link the actual projects with `svn:externals` for example. The plugin in Jenkins will then figure out to release one module which modules it needs to release first.

E.g to release `fish/shark -> 1.0`, it could need to release:

- a -> 1.1
- fish/salmon -> 1.2
- fish/shark -> 1.0

Comment: IMO, this is the best approach, theoretically speaking. pratically, i have to investigate, but thank you for pointing it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned that in your parent POM you are using "modules" tag. I propose you should use it - that way you can specify the line up for the project's build process.

To solve your current problem, create seperate module/project. In pom specify profiles to trigger ant operations. This should do the trick.

You would call the mvn command on parent dir as follows, i.e.:

```
mvn clean install -Pdeploy
```

Comment: Yes, i mentioned (in previous revision of the question) that parent "does not define any module", and i wrote that i don't want the parent to become an aggregator too. Final note, using ant task from maven to invoke a recursive maven?

Comment: sorry, i must have missed that in my reasoning.. and yes - use maven in a recursive manner - threat ant in this case as platform independent batch program.

Comment: a nice solution, but an anti-pattern: it includes external references in pom. If maven can't handle such a simple situation I think it's better to switch...

Answer (score 0):

Change the structure in SVN according to your dependencies:

In parent you have to define the list of modules and the dependencies between the modules have to be defined in the appropriate module.

```
parent (pom.xml)
 +-- aaa (plugin)
 +-- bbb (jar)
 +-- ccc (jar)
 +-- ddd (war)
 +-- eee (war)
```

The version should be the same for all modules like 3.0-SNAPSHOT after that you can simple release/deploy etc. from the root location.

If this is not the way you would go you should go via Jenkins to release all these projects separately.

Comment: i can't align versions and i can't make the parent an aggregator (like i wrote). So Jenkins seems to be the way...

Answer (score 0):

Now it's possible your modules are too fine grained, but personally I think the separate builds is the way to build you system and here's why.

The *parent* pom's primary job is to represent the next release.  That release could be a feature release involving several in-house modules or it could be a bug-fix release in which only a single module changes.

Given this the cycle goes something like this:

1. modify the *parent* pom's version to correspond to the next 'release'.
2. update the module versions being modified as part of the release.
3. update the modules to use the snapshot modified *parent* and make the changes.
4. update the module versions in the parent to their release version and release the *parent*.
5. update each module to use the released *parent* pom and release the modules.

The benefit of this approach is that, where a module is not modified you use the module version that were previously released (obtained from your release repo, so that's not 100% guaranteed) without a rebuild (which would happen with a multi-module approach) reducing the regression testing overhead.

If the number of modules changing with each release becomes a burden, it may be time to review your module structure, however the benefit of this approach is that the *parent* pom aligns all module versions across your system allowing reducing the regression testing effort and making it easy to make quick small released.

Comment: i disagree with "The parent pom's primary job is to represent the next release". Your cycle seems correct, but it requires more manual work than mine. And as final note, i can't review my module structure, since there is a common base (jars and plugins) that are reused on different high level projects (different customers supplies) so aligning versions for different customers is a contractual suicide